# Checking database contains the inserted values using flyway testcontainer to test migration scripts

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, database-migration, flyway, testcontainers

I am testing flyway migration scripts with testcontainers. I am using [flyway callbacks][1] afterMigrate to insert the data after migrations ran. My afterMigrate.sql contains some insert statements for example

```
Insert into table (id, ?, ?) values (12345,?,?)
```

After successfull migrations I want to check if the database contains the data or not. What I have been trying until now is below.

```
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import(FlywayCallback::class)
class DatabaseMigrationScriptIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var strategy: FlywayMigrationConfig

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var teamRepository : TeamRepository

  private val log = LogFactory.getLog(javaClass)

  @BeforeEach
  fun setUp() {
    //The function contains flyway.clean() to clean everything before each test
    strategy.cleanMigrateStrategy()
  }

  @Test
  fun runSqlInsertsAfterMigrationAndReadData() {
    val runAllMigrations = setFlywayConfigurationWithVersion("10")
    val migrate = runAllMigrations.migrate()
    val readSpecificTeamFromDB = teamRepository.findBy("12345")
    Assertions.assertThat(migrate.migrationsExecuted == 10)
    assertTrue(readSpecificTeamFromDB.get().email == "someone@someone.com")
  }


  private fun setFlywayConfigurationWithVersion(targetVersion: String ) : Flyway {
    val flyway = Flyway.configure()
      .target(targetVersion)
      .dataSource("jdbc:tc:mysql://localhost:3306", "testing", "testing")
      .locations("classpath:db/migration", "classpath:db/callback")
      .load()

    return flyway
  }
```

The classpath:db/callback contains afterMigrate.sql file.

All the migrations runs fine, but whenever I try to assert with the repository I get the error

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property teamRepository has not been initialized
```

P.S. I am using Kotlin.
Looking forward to your suggestions or ideas on How can I do it.
[1]: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/callbacks

Comment: Are you using `@DataJpaTest`? Can you please add the entire test setup?

Comment: @rieckpil editted.

Comment: What's the reason for manually triggering the Flyway migration? With both `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` the Flyway auto-configuration kicks in and you could verify the migration. Furthermore can you please share what you configure inside the `test` profile?

Comment: Do you mean in the test function runAllMigrations.migrate() ? Will edit the question with test properties